# Is data returned from a MySQL Connector/C query not in native C data format?

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

If I execute a query against the MySQL Connector/C library the data I'm getting back all appears to be in straight `char *` format, including numerical data types.

For example, if I execute a query that returns 4 columns, all of which are `INTEGER` in MySQL, rather than getting back 4 bytes worth of data (each byte representing a single column row value), I'm actually getting back 4 ASCII encoded character bytes, where `1` is actually a byte with the numeric value `49` in it (ASCII for `1`).

Is this accurate or am I just missing something complete?

Do I really need to then `atoi` that returned byte into an `int` in my code or is there a mechanism to get the native C data types out of the MySQL client directly?

I guess my real question is: is the `mysql_store_result` structure converting that data to ASCII encoded representations in a way that can be bypassed by my application code?

Comment: mysql ints are 32bit. for 4 ints, you should be getting back 16 bytes of data.

Comment: some tool you are using is leading you to miss understand the results.  How exactly are you "Getting back"

Comment: I'm most definitely not. A number of ```1000000` is being returned as an 8 byte string (ASCII = 49,48,48,48,48,48,48,0) - 7 bytes for the numbers and then a null byte.

Comment: mysql_store_result() followed by mysql_fetch_row(). The resulting MYSQL_ROW structure, in C is what is giving me this result.

Comment: It's not really possible for us to answer the question as presently posed, as it's unclear exactly what you're doing.  This is where a [mcve] comes in handy.

Comment: @Brandon below seems to verify what I'm seeing as well (server sends integers as text and Connector/C passes that data as-is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the data is sent on the wire as text in the MySQL protocol (I just confirmed this with Wireshark). So that means `mysql_store_result()` is not converting the data, it's just simply passing the data on as it was received. MySQL actually sends integers as text. I agree this always seemed like an odd design to me as well.

Comment: Yeah, baffling. It took me an hour to figure out that "49" wasn't an error and I needed to atoi() that byte back to int=1. It looks like the if you use prepared statements MySQL switches to a binary protocol for data encoding but that's not super helpful if your Connector/C code is taking arbitrary SQL from farther up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL originally only offered the [Text Protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/text-protocol.html) that you are currently using, in which (as you note) results are encoded as strings. MySQL v4.1 (released in April 2003) introduced the [Prepared Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html) protocol, which (amongst other things) transmits results in a binary format.

See [C API Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) for more information on how to use the latter protocol with Connector/C.